# Write data to SD card using Zynq

Tags: vhdl, fpga, zynq

I am developing an application using a ZedBoard (having a Xilinx Zynq FPGA). The board will be connected to multiple SD cards. One SD card is used to boot and program the FPGA (no problem here). Once that is over, the FPGA will have to do some data processing and write the contents to the second SD card using SDIO protocol. I have not come across any useful documentation/tutorials etc that show how to write data to the SD card either directly using VHDL logic or through the PS using AXI4 - DMA. Also, there are no free Xilinx or 3rd party IP blocks for SD card read/write access. Could someone please provide me with some tips/help regarding this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not mounting the SD card with a decent OS (GNU/Linux) and use the OS to store data files on the SD card?

Comment: Firstly, I have multiple SD cards (different for booting and for writing data). Secondly, I am allowed to use only bare-metal OS and no Linux

Answer (score 0):

To operate SD card in bare-metal applications, you can refer to the API of sdps driver in SDK installation directory, such as

```
C:\Xilinx\SDK\2015.3\data\embeddedsw\XilinxProcessorIPLib\drivers\sdps_v2_5
```

Answer (score 0):

Zynq PS7 has two SDIO controllers, so you can connect the second one to your second SD card socket. The second controller uses MIO pins, which on Zedboard are routed to PMOD connector JE.

The pinout of JE does not match that of Digilent's PMOD SDIO, but with some fly wires you can swizzle them to the correct connections.

The first answer points you to bare metal software to talk to the SD card.